# How to use a custom PersistField in TemplateHaskell model file?

Tags: haskell, yesod, template-haskell

I have the following model in `config/models`:

```
Post json
    title Text
    intro Text
    posted UTCTime default=now()
    published Bool default=true
    content Markdown Maybe
    cvId CvItemId Maybe
    projectId ProjectId Maybe
```

I have Yesod.Text.Markdown, which clearly defines a [PersistField](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-text-markdown-0.1.10/docs/Yesod-Text-Markdown.html#v:-36-fPersistFieldMarkdown) installed and imported in `src/Models.hs`. In this file, the models are generated using the following piece of code:

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")
```

On trying to build, I get the following error:

```
src/Model.hs:20:7: error:
    • Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘Markdown’
    • In the untyped splice:
        $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")
   |
20 |     $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")
   |
```

How do I make this work? I could probably make it work by avoiding TemplateHaskell, but I'd like to stick with this format, as it's much more elegant.

Comment: I assume you're importing `Text.Markdown` along with `Yesod.Text.Markdown`? The latter only defines an orphan instance, and as far as I can tell doesn't actually reexport the type.

Comment: That was indeed an issue, however, after adding that, I get ` No instance for (blaze-markup-0.8.2.1:Text.Blaze.ToMarkup
                         (Maybe Text.Markdown.Markdown))
        arising from a use of ‘toHtml’` in my Handler. It seems like the conversion to HTML isn't going as smoothly as it should.

Comment: It doesn't look like `Maybe a` instantiates `ToMarkup`. Perhaps try `fmap toHtml`?